# Auto Generate TOC for Article with Less than Four Headings

Tags: mediawiki

In the documentation https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting it states that an article will have a TOC generated if there are 4 or more headings.  We would like a TOC to be generated even if there is less than 4 headings.  Is this value customisable ?

Our workaround at present is to add **FORCETOC** to every page, but we would prefer it if this wasn't needed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It may not be possible, the 4 is hardcoded: https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/core/+/a60dcdc2e346d0b0df621daee991cbd26729cd4b/includes/parser/Parser.php#4083

Comment: Thanks!  I guess we could patch that file each time we upgrade between versions.  (I know you're not supposed to modify core but it does indeed look hard coded!)

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to add a config var that would do it. Something like `$wgMinTocCount`? Maybe open a ticket on Phabricator, to garner more discussion.

Comment: Many Thanks Sam - Happy to mark your comment as the answer (because I think it's as good as it can be at present!)

Comment: P.S. Hacked things with:$enoughToc = $this->mShowToc && (($numMatches >= 0) || $this->mForceTocPosition); and it's exactly what we want.

Comment: Sure, I've added it as an answer. :) And I'm not sure about your `>= 0` — what happens when it's zero? I guess it doesn't matter? I was thinking `> 0` would do.

Comment: Ah good point.  For a completely empty page it's going to try an generate a TOC.  Have changed it to > 0.  Thank you

Comment: Tgr's answer is better than mine, you should switch to that. :)

Comment: I know that we are adding FORCETOC, but (in general) I'm not sure how the other way could be used for less than four headings, e.g. say three headings ?

Comment: Doesn't `__FORCETOC__` add the ToC regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ToC heading count is not (currently) possible, as the `4` [is hardcoded](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/gitiles/mediawiki/core/+/a60dcdc2e346d0b0df621daee991cbd26729cd4b/includes/parser/Parser.php#4083). It wouldn't be a huge change to make it configurable though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a parser hook and change the parser's TOC settings. It's not elegant but doable. E.g. the [ForceTocOnEveryPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ForceTocOnEveryPage) extension does something like this:

```
$wgHooks['InternalParseBeforeLinks'][] = function ( &$parser, &$text ) {
    return $text . '__FORCETOC__';
};
```